# How to write the names that start with A - L to one file and the rest to another?

Tags: python

Hello my assignment is :

Create a system that allows the user to enter their name, title, surname, Dob, email and phone number. Once details are submitted, they should be written to a file.

Surnames that start with the letter `A`-`L` should be written to one file. Surnames that start with `M`-`Z` should be written to the second file. The user should have the option to view the contents of either file. Also it should output details in alphabetical order (by surname)
output details of user over 30.

The problem I am getting is  I don't know how to put surnames that start with the letter `A`-`L` should be written to one file and surnames that start with `M`-`Z` should be written to the second file.

```
import pickle
import time
print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
 from datetime import date
import pickle
import time
print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
from datetime import date

print("Hello welcome to the program")
title = input("Please enter your prefered title")
response = None 
if response not in ("Mr","Mrs","Miss","Dr"):
response = input("Incorrect try again.Please enter your prefered title")
name = input("Please enter your name")
surname =  input("Please enter your surname")
Dob = input("Enter your date of birth in this format: dd/mm/yy")
print("Your initials are:",name[0],surname[0])
fullname = title  + name +" "+ surname
```

Comment: Have you tried anything about writing to files? This looks like "do my homework for me".

Comment: you should give the input and expected output

Comment: How to write the names that start with A - L to one file and the rest to another?

Comment: no i am just asking how to write the names that start with A-L to one file and the rest to a different file?

Comment: Why are you importing stuff twice? Also, you should fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: that was by accident

Comment: Do you know how to test if a surname begins with a letter in `[A-L]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the alphabet-index of the first letter in the string:

```
    import string
    ind = string.lowercase.index(surname[0].lower())
    if ind <= 12: # A-L
        # Write to A-L file
    else:
        # Write to other file
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `...surname[0].lower()`?

Comment: Thanks Justen Ingels

Comment: @SiHa Thanks, my mistake, implemented your comment

Comment: There a is problem with the code                                                                             Ind = string.lowercase.index(surname[0].lower())
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lowercase'

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Note that `index` is relatively slow. Also, it will raise a ` ValueError` exception here if `surname[0]` isn't a letter in `string.lowercase`.

Comment: Thanks for the help@PM2Ring

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to test if a surname begins with a letter in the range `[A-L]` is by using a set. For example:

```
AtoL = set('ABCDEFGHIJKL')

data = ['Adams', 'Brown', 'Jones', 'Lucas', 
    'Morton', 'Peters', 'Smith', 'Walsh']

for name in data:
    initial = name[0].upper()
    print(initial, initial in AtoL)
    if initial in AtoL:
        print(name, 'in A-L')
    else:
        print(name, 'not in A-L')
```

#### output

```
A True
Adams in A-L
B True
Brown in A-L
J True
Jones in A-L
L True
Lucas in A-L
M False
Morton not in A-L
P False
Peters not in A-L
S False
Smith not in A-L
W False
Walsh not in A-L
```

Note that this code does not test if the surname is a valid surname, i.e., it begins with a letter. It does convert the initial to upper case, although that shouldn't be necessary in a real program, since you should validate the surname and correct its case (if necessary) before performing the A-L or M-Z test.